# Include files in scala i18n internationalization

Tags: scala, internationalization

I was wondering if there is any way to include references to other files in the scala messages files for internationalization (i18n).

Our messages files are getting pretty big and it's a pain to work with them. So I was wondering if there is some kind of import or something that can be made. Like `import somefile.en-US`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried rapture http://rapture.io/ ? rapture i18n (https://github.com/propensive/rapture-i18n) might be solution to your problem

Comment: @Jatin While rapture seems quite interesting and I might consider using it, I don't think it provides a solution for this particular problem as it seems to be an in-code solution for internationalization.